# Install OSX Snow Leopard and Windows XP 32-bit on same HDD?

Tags: macos, mac, multi-boot, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Mac OS X on Non Apple Hardware](https://superuser.com/questions/47337/installing-mac-os-x-on-non-apple-hardware)

How can I install OSX Snow Leopard and Windows XP 32-bit on same HDD?

Comment: MAC == Media Access Control
Mac == Macintonsh

Comment: someone has suggested this question is a duplicate (of http://superuser.com/questions/47337/installing-mac-os-x-on-non-apple-hardware ) ... but it is not clear to me that this is asking how to install OSX on non-Apple hardware.  it is only clear that this question is asking how to configure a dual-boot system with OSX and WinXP.  any duplicate should address that issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Boot Camp.  It is installed with Snow Leopard and can be found in `/Applications/Utilities/Boot Camp Assistant.app`

Boot Camp will create a second partition on your hard drive then assist you in installing Windows on it.  You can then dual-boot the machine.

If you want to use OS X at the same time as Windows, then you should use either [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org), [VMWare Fusion](http://www.vmware.com), or [Parallels Desktop](http://www.parallels.com) to run Windows in a virtual machine.

Comment: Run Boot Camp Assistant. It walks you through the process step by step.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, I believe Parallels and VMWare Fusion will allow you to run the Boot Camp partition in a virtual machine.  This can be quite handy when you only need a Windows program for a minute and don't want to have to reboot into the Boot Camp partition.  I saw an article the other day showing that Parallels was quite a bit faster than Fusion, fyi.  I use VirtualBox b/c it is free though, and it is great, but it can't virtualize the Boot Camp partition.